# Get direction to pins on map view

Tags: ios, swift, direction

Right now I'm coding a map in iOS and trying to figure out how to get directions for every pin that I coded that are permanently set on the map.

For instance, what I want my search bar to do is when I type the name of one of those permanent pins that I've placed, the search bar would recognize to go straight to that pin that I've placed.

I need to know how to get to the pins that I've placed on my map. I click on the pins but I don't get directions to it from current location. Thats what im trying to figure out .

Here's what I have so far for my pins that I've placed:

```
let location11 = CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: 33.232233, longitude: -111.232322)

let span11 =  MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)

let region11 = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location11, span: span11);

mapView.setRegion(region11, animated: true)

let Annotation10 = MKPointAnnotation()
Annotation10.coordinate = location11
Annotation10.title = " blahhh "
Annotation10.subtitle = "Campus"

mapView.addAnnotation (Annotation10)
```

And here is how I set up my searchBar delegate:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        let localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentCoordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.002, longitudeDelta: 0.002))
        localSearchRequest.region = region
        let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
        localSearch.start { (response, _) in
            guard let response = response else { return }
            guard let firstMapItem = response.mapItems.first else
            { return }
            self.getDirections(to: firstMapItem)
        }
    }
```

And here is my map view delegate:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = .yellow
            renderer.lineWidth = 5
            return renderer
        }
        if overlay is MKCircle {
            let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = .red
            renderer.fillColor = .red
            renderer.alpha = 0.005
            return renderer
        }
        return MKOverlayPathRenderer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there.....we need to know What's the problem you are getting or where you got stuck exactly or what you are not able to do ?

Comment: I need to know how to get to the pins that I've placed on my map. I click on the pins but I don't get directions to it from current location. Thats what im trying to figure out .

Answer (score 0):

First give your mkmapview variable delegate to your parent view/viewcontroller.
There is a delegate methods for getting the selected pin
First add the pin with proper information on the map with MKMapView delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")//Add your information here to the pin....like title,tag,color...}
```

Then on click of pin view this method will be invoked....get the pin and extract the information needed for the route calculation

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {//Get location and other info from view}
```